# Write R function with control flow that depends on argument value

Tags: r, function, refactoring

For small function, it is trivial to just write conditional statement based on the argument value. For example, I have a function that extracts variable label from an ex-STATA dataframe. There are two options for `output`-type, `environment` and `df`.

```
f_extract_stata_label <- function(df, output="environment") {
  if (output=="env") {
    lab_env <- new.env()
    for (i in seq_along(names(df))) {
      lab_env[[names(df)[i]]] <- attr(df, "var.labels")[i]  
    }
    return(lab_env)
  } else if (output=="df") {
    lab_df <- data.frame(var.name = names(d_tmp),
                         var.label = attr(d_tmp, "var.labels"))
    return(lab_df)
  }
}
```

However, I suspect that this is not good R idiom. First, how the function depends on `output` is not clear -- the reader has to read half way through the code to find out. Second, adding options to `output` in the future makes the function very hard to read.

So how should I rewrite this function?

Comment: Looks like it would fail if only given a value for 'df'. The "==" test doesn't do partial matching.

Comment: @BondedDust great point. What's the best way to write arguments that take multiple options (like the `family` argument in `glm`?). I'm new to write complex functions in R.

Comment: You can look at how `glm` does it by just typing `glm`. It first tests for type of the passed 'family'-argument to determine whether it needs to `get` a function or can just use a function-value. It then tests to see whether the result is actually a family-type function.

Comment: @Heisenberg Your comment about complex function argument is in anyway related to the question. My understanding is that you want to vary output type for the same function.

Comment: @agstudy In this specific case, I do want varying output type. But this is just an example of my bigger question, which is how to elegantly handle control flow within the function based on argument values.

Comment: `switch` may be what you want

Answer (score 1):

R uses this kind of pattern in its core stats libraries where "label" strings make sense. These are functions where R's dispatch system is not that useful. That said, what you want is still dispatch-like.

You could refactor it to use a switch that calls a function dedicated to a specific output type. Two things happen then. First, the extra function call makes it clear what context you're in when using the traceback. Second, it makes the functions smaller and easier to read.

I would question whether you really want to use a dispatch function though, and why separate direct functions are not appropriate.